# Can't add syntax highlighter to textedit

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developing in C++ and QT. I'm want to create text editor and I have problem.
With

```
PythonSyntaxHighlighter *highlighter;
highlighter = new PythonSyntaxHighlighter(ui->editor->document());
```

I can't compile my program, because it's four errors:

- 'PythonSyntaxHighlighter' was not declared in this scope
- 'highlighter' was not declared in this scope
- expected type-specifier before 'PythonSyntaxHighlighter'
- expected ';' before 'PythonSyntaxHighlighter'

Here is my texteditor.cpp:

```
#include "texteditor.h"
#include "ui_texteditor.h"
#include "PythonSyntaxHighlighter.h"

TextEditor::TextEditor(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::TextEditor)
{
    PythonSyntaxHighlighter *highlighter;
    highlighter = new PythonSyntaxHighlighter(ui->editor->document());
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

TextEditor::~TextEditor()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

UPDATE:
pythonsyntaxhighlighter.cpp: http://pastebin.com/yFvXahiX
pythonsyntaxhighlighter.h: http://pastebin.com/TpR4X3sm
no matching function for call to 'PythonSyntaxHighlighter::PythonSyntaxHighlighter(QTextDocument*)'
     PythonSyntaxHighlighter *pythonHighlighter = new PythonSyntaxHighlighter(ui->editor->document());

Comment: Forgot to `#include "PythonSyntaxHighlighter.h"`?

Comment: Now, I have next error: no matching function for call to 'PythonSyntaxHighlighter::PythonSyntaxHighlighter(QTextDocument)'

Answer (score 0):

You have to include PythonSyntaxHighlighter.

For example:

```
#include "pythonsyntaxhighlighter.h"
```

**Update:**

```
ui->editor->document();
```

This line of Code retuns a Pointer: QTextDocument*.

Your Constructor in PythonSyntaxHighlighter should support this parameter:

```
PythonSyntaxHighlighter::PythonSyntaxHighlighter(QTextDocument* TextDoc)
{
}

PythonSyntaxHighlighter::~PythonSyntaxHighlighter()
{
}
```

Second Problem:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
PythonSyntaxHighlighter *highlighter;
highlighter = new PythonSyntaxHighlighter(ui->editor->document());
```

**First setupUi and now you can access ui Members! SetupUi initialise them**

Comment: Now, I have next error: no matching function for call to 'PythonSyntaxHighlighter::PythonSyntaxHighlighter(QTextDocument)'

Comment: Is The Constructor PythonSyntaxHighlighter::PythonSyntaxHighlighter(QTextDocument) in your class "PythonSyntaxHighlighter"?

Comment: First setupUi! Look at my answer.

Comment: Nothing changed: no matching function for call to 'PythonSyntaxHighlighter::PythonSyntaxHighlighter(QTextDocument*)'
     PythonSyntaxHighlighter *pythonHighlighter = new PythonSyntaxHighlighter(ui->editor->document());

Comment: Post your class PythonSyntaxHighlighter. What is editor? A Textedit?

Comment: In you header: PythonSyntaxHighlighter(); There is QTextDocument* missing. -> PythonSyntaxHighlighter(QTextDocument* doc).

Comment: Next: PythonSyntaxHighlighter.h:7: error: expected ')' before '*' token
     PythonSyntaxHighlighter(QTextDocument *parent)

Comment: You need to declare QTextDocument. Put "class QTextDocument;" into the header. For the next error use new Question or google, this one is answered.

Comment: Please set this Question as answered. Thank you.